# google sheet query optimize syntax in where clause with many columns

Tags: google-sheets, optimization, syntax, where-clause, clause

Hi my gsheets query studying are in progress and I'm looking for optimization of formulas that can be become very long with many datas.
In this case I can't find a method to optimize the lenght becaue of the syntax, I think...

I tryied this formula =query({A:G};"select Col1 where "Col"&arrayformula(TEXTJOIN(" OR Col";;SEQUENCE(1;6;2)&"="&""&I2&""))")

Unfortunatly with arrayformula and Text join doesn't work, but copy/paste the result of that formula works properly.

Here's the link to the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y3UhNZjSbYck2MKptE8kd_2_Jj6UkFZbaIWI8kMsevs/edit#gid=1401842419)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=query({A:G};"select Col1 where Col"&join(" OR Col";index(sequence(1;5;2)&"="&I2)))
```

[image]